# PDE refresher: Verifying a solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

My PDEs are a bit rusty, and this seems all too simple, but something isn't quite right. I have the following equation of Thomson:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}v(x,t)=\gamma\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}v(x,t)-\alpha v(x,t)\,,
\end{equation}
with $\alpha$, $\gamma>0$. Now I am to show that
\begin{equation}
v(x,t)=e^{-\alpha t}u(x,t)
\end{equation}is its general solution, where $u(x,t)$ solves $\partial u(x,t)/\partial t$=$\gamma\partial^2 u(x,t)/\partial x^2$ (the heat equation).

My normal approach to such a thing would be to differentiate the assumed solution with $t$, set the result equal to the RHS of the original equation, rearrange to isolate $u(x,t)$, then respectively differentiate that once with $t$ and twice with $x$. The latter two differentiations should produce expressions that are off by a factor of $\gamma$, verifying the needed properties. But some cursory inspection discounts that possibility: there'd be a fourth derivative in one of the expressions, and a mixed partial in the other.

What am I missing, and how can I start on the correct foot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're overthinking this. Observe that

\begin{align*}
v_t &= -\alpha v + e^{-\alpha t} u_t \\
&= -\alpha v + \gamma e^{-\alpha t}u_{xx}\\
&= -\alpha v + \gamma v_{xx}.
\end{align*}

The first equality comes from differentiating $v$, the second equality comes from the heat equation, and the third equality comes again from differentiating $v$.

Answer (score 1):

$\partial_t v=e^{-\alpha t}u_t-\alpha e^{-\alpha t}u= \gamma e^{-\alpha t}u_{xx}-\alpha v=\gamma v_{xx}-\alpha v$